# ImportError: cannot import name 'Author' from 'hymnbook.models.author' (C:\..\hymnbook\models\author.py)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make migration of this app that we have been developing, but when I run `python manage.py migrate` I get this error:

> from .author import Author
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'Author' from 'hymnbook.models.author' (C:\Users\Asus-PC\Py
>   charmProjects\hinario\ourhymnbook-py\novo\hymnbook\hymnbook\models\author.py)

I'm using the version 
3.7 of python and django 3.0.6

ATT: All models are in same directory but in separeted files

This is the author model

```
from django.db import models
from .hymn import Hymn


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=False)
    birth = models.DateTimeField()
    death = models.DateTimeField()
    hymn = models.ManyToManyField(Hymn, on_delete=models.CASCADE())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name, self.hymn
```

And this is the hymn model

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from .verse import Verse
from .language import Language
from .hymnbook import HymnBook
from .author import Author
from .genre import Genre


class Hymn(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hymnBook = models.ForeignKey(HymnBook, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I will be very thankful if some help me with this!

Since now my thanks!

Comment: You have a circular import. You shouldn't create circular relationships and dependencies, period. In Django you only need to declare a relationship from one of the models, not from both.

Comment: @deceze is right, you have author model which importing hymn, and hymn is importing author, and there is an import error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sthino_IV mentioned in the comments, you have a [circular import](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/):

- author.py is attempting to import from .hymn
- hymn.py is attempting to import from .author

You have also declared a ManyToManyField on each model to the other. This is not how typical many-to-many relationships are defined. Have a read of the example in the docs about [pizza and toppings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).

To fix the issue, you will need to edit authors.py:

- remove `from .hymn import Hymn`
- remove `hymn = models.ManyToManyField(Hymn, on_delete=models.CASCADE())`

I also suggest you update your `Hymn` model, renaming the `author` attribute as `authors` and adding a `related_name`:

```
class Hymn(models.Model):
    # other fields go here
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='hymns')
```

This will allow you to access all authors on a `Hymn` instance, and all hymns on an `Author` instance.

You will probably need to delete the migration file in /migrations and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you keeping all models as seperated file ?. this is not a django standard
You can define your models right in the `models.py` file and can import wherever you want

```
from .models import Author
#if model resides in same directory
```

```
from module.models import Author
#if model resides in another directory named "module"
```